# Program isn't retrieving from taskbar after minimizing it

Tags: c#, wpf

I'll give some background about what I am trying to do:

I have created a customized button that should minimize my window with a fade out animation so here's the code of it:

```
private void minimize_Window(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var anim = new DoubleAnimation(0, (Duration)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    anim.Completed += (s, _) => this.Minimize();
    this.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, anim);
}

private void Minimize()
{
    WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
}
```

It works perfectly fine, though the problem is that when I try to retrieve my program from the task bar it won't do anything (I am not able to see the program when I click on it from the taskbar after it minimized). What I understand from it is that the opacity of my program is being set to 0 while it got minimized(because of the animation). So I used the Activated event calling that method:

```
private void set_Opacity(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rectangle2.Opacity = 1;
    WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
}
```

And still, same issue. Hope you could help.

Thank you very much.
**Please let me know if any other explanation is needed.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using another animation to set the opacity back to 1:

```
    private void set_Opacity(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var anim = new DoubleAnimation(1, (Duration)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0));
        this.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, anim);
    }
```

**EDIT**: the reason why this approach works and simply setting the opacity to 1 doesn't is due to [dependency property value setting precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx#listing).  In short, values set by animations take priority over 'local' values set, i.e. those values set by assigning to the property.

In your case, the animation had finished, but it was still 'holding on' to the `Opacity` dependency property.  However, if you create your fading-out animation with

```
    anim.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop;
```

then the animation will 'release' the `Opacity` property once it finishes and you don't then need another animation to set it back to 1.  Your original `set_Opacity` method should then work.

Note also that you shouldn't assign `WindowState = WindowState.Normal` in your `set_Opacity` method.  If you maximize the window, click your button to minimize it, and then click on the taskbar button, the window doesn't reappear maximized.

Comment: Thank you so much!! do you know why just setting the opacity to 1 like I did isn't working? You got my +1 and V :) just please answer my question if you have any idea why. thanks again!!

Comment: @idish: I've edited my answer to explain why just setting the opacity to 1 didn't work.  It turns out also that there's a way of setting up your animation so that you don't need another animation to reset the opacity, and I've added that as well.

Comment: I see, thank you for the explanation, by the way, in what cases I should use the FillBeaviour.HoldEnd? Where is it actually usable?

Comment: @idish: no idea, sorry.  I've not done a lot with WPF animations before and I didn't even know about the `FillBehavior` property until yesterday.

Comment: Hahaha, I see well thanks again and BTW, I've just set another question if you could help it'd be awesome. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095859/how-to-get-the-children-of-an-element-wpf