# how to get the children of an element WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a stackpanel that contains an Image and a TextBlock. I'm raising an event once double click is being performed by the user.(**P.S** - I'm adding the StackPanel and it's children (the Image and the TextBlock programatically if it matters).

Now, I need to get the TextBlock element from inside the stackpanel, I understand that I should do it using DataBinding, but I'm a beginner to WPF, and really haven't found any examples about it in the web. I'll be glad for an explanation, thank you very much!

(I learnt about DataBinding a while ago).

Comment: Why are you adding the StackPanel and its children programmatically?  Chances are good that you can get what you want purely in Xaml, and either bind the clicks to a command, or simply reference the TextBlock by name.

Comment: @MichaelGraczyk I am achieving the data I display (e.g - stackpanel) from a Database.

Comment: You should almost never have to add UI elements from code.  If the UI isn't changing during runtime, you shouldn't be adding any UI elements from code.  You can give elements a name with the x:Name directive, and then access then by that name from the code-behind.

Comment: @MichaelGraczyk The program I am developing is a chat, the thing is that I get the contacts he has from a Database, how am I able to know how many elements I should add in the xaml?

Comment: Use a ListView, and bind its ItemsSource property to the Collection that you retrieve from the database.

Comment: @MichaelGraczyk Can you please give me a tutorial for using such things in WPF? and BTW, what's the reason that I shouldn't add elements programatically?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12729/discussion-between-idish-and-michael-graczyk)

Comment: If you're comfortable with data binding, then you should read the msdn section on binding to collections: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#binding_to_collections.  

Adding elements programmatically couples program logic tightly to the presentation.  It makes the code harder to read, harder to modify, and much much harder to change visually.  If you keep UI and code separate, you can make the app look pretty, and also work, without having to worry about the two at the same time.

Also it is way easier to lay the view out in Xaml (or CSS or whatever) than in code.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A simple way of getting the first child element of a certain type (e.g. TextBlock) is this:

```
var textBlock = panel.Children.OfType<TextBlock>().FirstOrDefault();
```

You either get the first TextBlock or `null` if there isn't any.

Answer (score 0):

You need to DataBind `TextBlock` `Text` (?) element to your class - like so:

In XAML

```
<TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock"
   Text={Binding ShowThis, Mode=OneWay} />
```

in class:

```
 public class MyDataContextClass
 {
     private string showThis = string.Enpty;
     public string ShowThis
     {
         get {return showThis;}
         set
         {
              showThis = value;
              if (PropertyChanged != null)
                  PropertyChanged(....);
         }
      }
  }
```

and you must DataBing Xaml to class. (May be in constructor ?)

```
  public class MyXamlWindow
  {
       public MyXamlWindow()
       {
             this.DataContext = new MyDataContextClass();
       }
   }
```

There's **a lot** of ways to do all above

Comment: And of course if he only wants to access the TextBlock,  he can simply use the x:Name => MyTextBlock.