# Cant make a Label visible after a Storyboard has hidden it

Tags: c#, wpf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Program isn't retrieving from taskbar after minimizing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065518/program-isnt-retrieving-from-taskbar-after-minimizing-it)

Background - I have a ListBox with each item containing a couple of buttons. When the buttons are clicked I want a Label to be displayed with a message and then fade out. I've got a method to handle setting the content, making it visible and then fading it out using a Storyboard (see below).

This works fine the first time, but any further clicks in the same Listbox item result in nothing happening - debugging shows the Content being changed etc but the control never becomes visible. Can anyone point out the obvious thing I'm missing (or alternatively, a way that works)?

```
private void SetLabelMessageContent(Panel panel, string message)
{
  Label lblMessage = panel.Children.OfType<Label>().First();
  if (lblMessage != null)
  {
    // Set content and make sure its visible
    lblMessage.Content = message;
    lblMessage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    lblMessage.Opacity = 1.0;

    // Set the storyboard going - will fade it out
    var storyboard = lblMessage.FindResource("MessageFadeOut");
    if (storyboard is Storyboard)
    {
      ((Storyboard)storyboard).Clone().Begin(lblMessage);
    }
  }
}
```

MessageFadeOut resource is:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="MessageFadeOut">
  <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:2.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.25"/>
  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:2.25" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        <Visibility>Hidden</Visibility>
      </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

Comment: I gave a similar answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11066984

Comment: @LukeWoodward that was the problem. I've solved it by having the Storyboard force the Visibility back to Visible rather than doing it via the code.